# Find the sum $\frac{7}{(2)(3)}( \frac 13) + \frac{9}{(3)(4)} (\frac 13)^2 + \frac{11}{(4)(5)} (\frac 13)^3..$ upto 10 terms

Tags: sequences-and-series

I found the $n^{th} $ of the series as
$$\frac{5+2n}{(1+n)(2+n)} (\frac 13)^{n}$$

Has the $\frac 13 $ and $5+2n$ not been there, it would have been a telescoping series

Similarly, had the $(1+n)(2+n)$ term not been been there, it would have been an arithmetic geometric progression.

I know how to evaluate them separately, but not at the same time

How do I solve this one?

Comment: It's only ten terms. Why do you think a solution other than just keying the terms into your calculator is needed? Truncated series are often used to get estimates for the (known) sum of the entire series. The possibly most famous case being Shanks calculating $\pi$ up to 500 decimal places :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I am not supposed to have a calculator at my disposal

Comment: Partial fraction expansion!

Comment: Ok. Sorry about the jumping to a conclusion without looking at the series more closely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make a partial fraction expansion:

$$\frac{5+2n}{(1+n)(2+n)}=\frac{3}{(1+n)}-\frac{1}{(2+n)}$$

Multiplication by $(\frac 13)^{n}$ gives:

$$\frac{1}{(1+n)}(\frac 13)^{n-1}-\frac{1}{(1+(n+1))}(\frac 13)^{n}$$

yielding indeed a telescoping sum.

Comment: I am not able to observe the series telescope. Can you elaborate? (Also I think you added 2 minus signs instead of one)

Comment: Sorry for the typo. Minus sign corrected. (to be continued)